# where can i learn electronics from intro to advance digital

Tags: electronics

I'd like some well put video series of like 30 videos. Or anything but it needs to thorough and in easy English...less mundane. So far all resources i have found either go upto resistors code or of projects that tell you do this and this and this and tada you got this.

Is there really no online resource for people to learn electronics. I want further master analog and do move on to digital cause it's better to spend 0.40 cents.... than
 spend $95 on components and get the whole thing on tiny chip.

Please bare with me like six months i have been searching for legit source, material that is meant to teach you. I like pictures and colors.

Comment: The Art of Electronics - Horowitz & Hill

Comment: This type of question would be great for [our chat 
rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), but for Q&A it's generally regarded as [not 
constructive](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): **"As it currently
stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to 
be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will 
likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.**  There is a
[relevant discussion on this topic at our meta 
site](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/29/350)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MOOCS are so popular nowadays, that I'm not sure you haven't check it out. Anyway, let's give it a shot.

Please, have a look at this courses:

**edx.org**

https://www.edx.org/course-list/allschools/electronics/allcourses

**www.coursera.org**

You can also check out [www.coursera.org](http://www.coursera.org). it's similar to mentioned above.

**MIT OpenCourseware**

And last but not least, you can also try to find something here:
[MIT OpenCourseware electronics](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/find-by-topic/#cat=engineering&subcat=electricalengineering&spec=electronics)

**UPDATE:** Also, there's a site with all MOOCS in one place: [class-central.com](https://www.class-central.com/)